# How to associate/link content items in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a website that tracks cars in a fleet. On the site I have a few content items:

1. Automobile
2. Engine
3. Accessories

The Automobile content item will contain specifics on that auto (make/model, year, etc).

The Engine content item will contain info about the engine itself (mileage, time until next service, etc).

The Accessories content item will contain info about other items on that auto (roof signage, review mirror dice, air freshener used, etc ... these are just examples of what could be on that content type page).

The Engine and Accessories content items will start off in one auto, but they may be moved to other autos as time goes on. For instance:
Month 1: Auto A has Engine K and Accessories T
Month 2: Auto A has Engine L and Accessories U
Month 3: Auto A has Engine M and Accessories V

I'd like to know what my options are to associate/link those Engine and Accessories content items to that Auto, and then link them to a different Auto when the time comes to change them out. Any recommendations on how that can be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would just create 3 different content types with their respective fields and use the [references module](http://drupal.org/project/references) to attach engines & accessories to the automobile content type. Either using the autocomplete widget or select list, depending upon how much content you have.

Example:

```
Automobile
-Make
-Model
-Engine Ref Field
-Accessories Ref Field

Engine
-Options
-Other Options

Accessories
-Options
-More options
```

This way makes it easy to attach an engine and accessories to your automobile nodes & allows you to quickly change what items are referencing it month to month.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation! I ended up installing the Entity Reference Module (http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) instead. I added the Entity Ref field to the Engine content type, and I can now use the drop-list to select the Auto while I edit the Engine content item... looks like this is the perfect solution. Thanks again!